# get entity from query object by keyname

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a query object of artist.tracks

```
artist = db.ReferenceProperty(Artist,collection_name='tracks')
```

and I want to get the entity of the query object by its keyname so

artist.tracks = all tracks from artist

I want to get the track from this query with keyname of 'thisKeyName'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the key_name, you don't need a query use [Model.get_by_key_name](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name):

```
Kind.get_by_key_name('thisKeyName')
```